# What changed with MediaCodec on Android 12

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, android-12

I created an Audio MediaCodec .
When i dequeueOutputBuffer() , the timestamp in BufferInfo is what i put into queueInputBuffer() before the Android Version 12 .
But after Android 12 , the timestamp is not what i put into it . The real action is , every timestamp i get from dequeueOutputBuffer is the previous one + 23219 us .

Now after dequeueOutputBuffer() , i reset the presentationTimeUs int the ByteBuffer with the last timestamp .

Is there anyone who knows that ? And what should i do to suit for that ?